# Custom Table View Controller crashes with "initWithCoder: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, uiviewcontroller, twitter-fabric

Based on the sample code provided here ([Show Timelines](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios/show-timelines)), I have created a custom TWTRSearchViewController:

**.h:**

```
#import <TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h>
@interface TWTRSearchViewController : TWTRTimelineViewController
@end
```

**.m:**

```
#import "TWTRSearchViewController.h"
@interface TWTRSearchViewController ()
@end

@implementation TWTRSearchViewController
- (instancetype)init {
    TWTRAPIClient *APIClient = [[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient];
    TWTRSearchTimelineDataSource *searchTimelineDataSource = [[TWTRSearchTimelineDataSource alloc] initWithSearchQuery:@"#twitterflock" APIClient:APIClient];
    return [super initWithDataSource:searchTimelineDataSource];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

This is the header of TWTRTimelineViewController.h:

```
//
//  TWTRTimelineViewController.h
//  TwitterKit
//
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Twitter. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TWTRTimelineDataSource.h"

/**
 This class is a `UITableViewController` subclass that displays `TWTRTweetTableViewCell` cells. It handles cell-reuse, cell-configuration, and loading more tweets from the given timeline once the last cell is reached.

 ## Usage

 Initialize this class with any object that conforms to the `TWTRTimelineDataSource` protocol. We provide two such classes, `TWTRUserTimelineDataSource` and `TWTRSearchTimelineDataSource`. These provide `TWTRTweet` objects to this table view which then configures the instances of `TWTRTweetTableViewCell`.

    // Create the data source
    TWTRAPIClient *client = [Twitter sharedInstance].APIClient;
    TWTRUserTimelineDataSource *dataSource = [[TWTRUserTimelineDataSource alloc] initWithScreenName:@"jack" APIClient:client];

    // Create the timeline view controller
    TWTRTimelineViewController *timeline = [[TWTRTimelineViewController alloc] initWithDataSource:dataSource];

 ## Loading More

 This class loads the first batch of `TWTRTweet` objects from the Twitter API when `viewWillAppear:` is received. It also handles loading more tweets automatically once the last cell has been shown.

 */
@interface TWTRTimelineViewController : UITableViewController

/**
   Initializes a timeline view controller. Does not start loading tweets until 
   `viewWillAppear:` is called. 

   This method must be used to initialize this class. The `init` method is unavailable.

   @param dataSource   Required. A timeline data source object that conforms to the `TWTRTimelineDataSource` protocol.

   @return A fully initialized `TWTRTimelineViewController` or nil if the data source is missing.
 */
- (instancetype)initWithDataSource:(id<TWTRTimelineDataSource>)dataSource __attribute((nonnull)) NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;

/**
  The source of `TWTRTweet` objects for this `TWTRTimelineViewController`.

  May be set to update the tweets being shown by this table view. Must be set on the main thread.
 */
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<TWTRTimelineDataSource> dataSource;

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style __attribute__((unavailable("Use -initWithDataSource: instead")));

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder __attribute__((unavailable("Use -initWithDataSource: instead")));

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil __attribute__((unavailable("Use -initWithDataSource: instead")));

@end
```

After the app starts, it crashes right away with the error message: `-[TWTRSearchViewController initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a88f1d0`. The app crashes even before `init` or `viewDidLoad` is called.

What is wrong my code? Any idea on what I might have missed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Override `initWithCoder:` method in your subclass and do the same thing you do in your current `init`

Comment: Isn't there a better way to instantiate my view controller than by using the storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

I had kind of the same kind of bug, also with no logical explanation of it. Even swiping derived data and such did not work. What I finally did was, create a new class with a "2" in the name to distinguish it from the first, copy the code from the crashing viewcontroller over and then it worked.